# Crear varios elementos <li> con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy creando una lista de películas y tengo que mostrar cada una en un elemento `<li>`, pero en el momento de añadirlo en el html con `appendChild`, carga el listado completo en un solo `li`.

```
var pelis = [
    {
        Nombre: "El señor de los anillos",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Regreso al Futuro",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Los increibles 2",
        Genero: "Animación"
    },
];

function addLi() {
    var contenido;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    for (i = 0; i < pelis.length; i++) {
        contenido = "Nombre:" + pelis[i].Nombre + " || Genero: " + pelis[i].Genero;
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contenido));
        document.querySelector("#lista-pelis").appendChild(li).appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="lista-pelis.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lista de películas</h1>
        <ul id="lista-pelis"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solucionado, el problema estaba en que cargaba el javascript antes del  `HTML`. Para corregirlo, puse el script de js: `<script src="lista-pelis.js" type="application/javascript"></script>` al final del `<body>`

Answer (score 3):

Lo único que te faltaba era incluir la creación del `<li>` y del `<p>` que luego insertas en el **DOM** dentro del bucle, para que por cada iteración de este te cree uno.

```js
var pelis = [
    {
        Nombre: "El señor de los anillos",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Regreso al Futuro",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Los increibles 2",
        Genero: "Animación"
    },
];

addLi();

function addLi() {
    var contenido;
    for (i = 0; i < pelis.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      contenido = "Nombre:" + pelis[i].Nombre + " || Genero: " + pelis[i].Genero;
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contenido));
      document.querySelector("#lista-pelis").appendChild(li).appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="lista-pelis.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lista de películas</h1>
        <ul id="lista-pelis"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You win this time... :)

Comment: Por muy poco :D

Comment: tampoco funciona así, de todas formas  llamo al método desde la consola del navegador. Gracias

Comment: Si aquí funciona, como puedes comprobar si le das al botón ejecutar, y en tu página no, es que algo tienes que tener ahí. ¿A qué te refieres con que no te funciona? ¿Te sigue metiendo todo el listado en un solo `<li>`? ¿Te arroja algún error la consola del navegador?

Comment: Da error en el `appendChild()`:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: ¿Desde dónde llamas a la función `addLi()`? Seguramente te esté pasando porque estás llamando a la función antes de que haya cargado el **HTML** por lo que la línea `document.querySelector("#lista-pelis").appendChild(li).appendChild(p);` te estaría fallando al no encontrar el elemento `#lista-pelis`.

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro cómo lo hago yo con una pequeña librería que me armé

```
document.getElementByTagName("body").innerHTML =
  UL({id:"lista-pelis"}, ()=>{
    var inner = ""
    for(var i =0; i<pelis.length; i++){
       inner+= LI({}, ()=>
          "Nombre:" + pelis[i].Nombre + " || Genero: " + pelis[i].Genero;
       )
    }
    return inner;
   })
```

Te invito a que la veas:
https://github.com/gianlucafiore/VanillaJsEloquent

saludos!